# Failed to use the Glassfish server's appclient to run the producer program

Tags: java, glassfish, java-io, java-ee-7

I am writing simple jakarta messaging applications with NetBeans and Glassfish. I followed the tutorial "The Jakarta EE 7 Tutorial" step by step. After successfully building all the "simple" Examples, I use the `appclient -client target/producer.jar queue 3` in my windows terminal. While Can't send the message.
I'm using Glassfish-5.0.1 . It looks like I can't use the `appclient`. Can anyone give me some help?

[The Jakarta EE 7/ 46.2 Writing Simple JMS Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jms-examples002.htm#BNCFA)

```
jakartaee-tutorial-examples-master\jakartaee-tutorial-examples-master\jms\simple\producer>appclient -client target/producer.jar queue 3
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\?????ó\AppData\Local\Temp\acc7678140812900140496.dat (System cannot find the specified path。)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.agent.AppClientContainerAgent.optionsValue(AppClientContainerAgent.java:104)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.agent.AppClientContainerAgent.premain(AppClientContainerAgent.java:83)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File not found exception means you either did not have a correct specified path or you gave a path with no file for the inputstream to read.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I run the program successfully after I changed my Windows user name to C:\Users\English.